# sum values in vuejs2

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

hi i have this vuejs2 code

```
totals() {
    this.total = 0;
    console.log(this.total_without_discount);
    console.log(this.total_taxs);
    console.log(this.total_discount);
    this.total += this.total_without_discount;
    this.total += this.total_taxs;
    this.total += this.total_discount;
    return Number(this.total).toFixed(this.comma);
},
```

now when i get the result back i gat Nan 
all these functions are in `computed` 
how can i sum the values inside totals function and return it back 
thanks

Comment: One of `total_without_discount`, `total_taxs` or `total_discount` returns either `undefined` or `NaN`. Without a proper [mcve] we cannot tell you exactly what is going on besides: Make sure that they do not return that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) or [parseFloat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat), depending on the data type and precision needed:

```
totals() {
    this.total = 0;

    this.total += parseFloat(this.total_without_discount);
    this.total += parseFloat(this.total_taxs);
    this.total += parseFloat(this.total_discount);

    return parseFloat(this.total).toFixed(this.comma);
},
```